# Admob: Ad element loads "on top" of layout

Tags: android, layout, admob, overlap

[image]

As you can see from the image, the Ad element gets loaded on TOP of layout instead of below it.

How can I make the List resize itself once the Ads are loaded? I want the ads to come below the list (not on top of it) (currently one element of the list cannot be seen due to overlapping)

This is my layout (RelativeLayout):

```
<!-- dynamic fragment -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Populating ads:

```
private void populateAdView() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); // Emulator

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a151410c0882629");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
    ll.addView(adView);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //reduce FrameLayout height
    //adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in `android:layout_above="@+id/adLayout"` on your FrameLayout to tell it to specifically sit on top of the ad layout.